# Ansible - Reference 'ansible_ssh_pass' in a task?

Tags: ansible

I understand that the `ansible_ssh_pass` (and similarly `ansible_become_pass`) variables are *settable* via inventories. E.g.:

```
[some_group:vars]
ansible_ssh_pass=some_password
```

But is the same *referencable* from a task *without explicitly setting it in an inventory?* E.g. if I simply provide the password with `--ask-pass`?

The use case would be to mount a CIFS share with an authorized account (which would simply be a user's SSH account as we have Active Directory in our environment). I've tried using the documented variables, e.g.:

```yaml
- name: Mount a drive
  sudo: true
  mount: state="mounted" fstype="cifs" opts="username={{ ansible_ssh_user }}, password={{ ansible_ssh_pass }} src=..."
```

But this results in an error:

> fatal: [some.machine] => One or more undefined variables: 'ansible_ssh_pass' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question

> *But is the same *referencable* from a task *without explicitly setting it in an inventory*? E.g. if I simply provide the password with `--ask-pass`?*

the short answer is yes. A minimal test playbook for a Remote Node

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Show variables
    debug:
      msg:
        - "Provided user: {{ ansible_user }}"
        - "Provided password: {{ ansible_password }}"
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook --user ${ADMIN_USER} --ask-pass remote.yml
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show variables] ***********
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - 'Provided user: admin_user'
  - 'Provided password: 12345678'
```

and just providing the given password.